# Periodically execute function every n minutes while doing other stuffs

Tags: python, variables, auto-update

I want to basically update a variable value every 5 minutes by calling a function in python while doing other tasks if time is not 5 minutes. I tried to use strftime to keep time but got lost. Not sure what mistake I am making. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    variable = 0
    start_time = strftime("%M")
    While True:
        {do something here}
        current_time = strftime("%M")
        diff = int(start_time) - int(current_time)
        if diff is 5 minutes:
            function_call() #updates the variable
        else:
            Use the old variable value
```

Comment: If my answer was sufficient could you please accept my answer? Click on the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you want to an asynchronous function call take a look at: [Timer Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) and use them as such (from the docs):

   ```
   from threading import Timer
   t = Timer(300.0, function_call)
   t.start() # after 300 seconds, function_call will be called
   ```
2. Otherwise the simpler solution (without threads) is just to check the difference from time calls as such (as you were trying to do):

   ```
   from time import time
   start_time = time()
   # do stuff
   if time() - start_time > 300: # 300 secs
       function_call()
   ```

So using the 2nd option your code could look like this:

```
from time import time
variable = 0
start_time = time()
While True:
    {do something here}
    current_time = time()
    diff = current_time - start_time
    if diff > 5*60:
        function_call() #updates the variable
        start_time = current_time
    else:
        Use the old variable value
```

Comment: While True: should be while True: